# react-native/Typescript: how to pass autoComplete value to TextInput as the parent component prop? What's the correct type?

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

Consider I have a custom component like this with a `TextInput` inside (for example a modal input dialog):

```
interface Props {
    ...
    autoComplete: string;
}

const ModalInputDialog = (props: Props) => {

    ...

    return (<TextInput autoComplete={props.autoComplete} ... />);

};
```

The Typescript compiler complains that **"No overloads matches this call"**. The problem is that I don't know which is the correct type for the `autoComplete` property. It isn't string.

By inspecting `TextInput` It seems that there a big object called `TextInputAndroidProps`, but It doesn't work either.

Which is the correct type I'm searching for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the type from `TextInputAndroidProps` directly using TypeScript as follows.

```js
import { TextInput, TextInputAndroidProps } from "react-native";

interface Props {
    autoComplete: TextInputAndroidProps['autoComplete'];
}
```

In my current project, the prop is still called `autoCompleteType`, thus for older versions this is done similarly.

```js
import { TextInputAndroidProps } from "react-native";

interface Props {
    autoComplete: TextInputAndroidProps['autoCompleteType'];
}
```

You will need the [react-native types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts) in your project, but I guess this is clear.

Notice as well that this is an android only prop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clear explaination. What I was missing is that I could use the brackets operator with the property name.